# differentiability, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I've been looking at this and have no idea where to start or how to solve this

Comment: Start with the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Also you can use the cauchy-reimann equations.

Comment: how would I apply the Cauchy Riemann equations to this? @ShoumanDas

Comment: By plugging the thing you have into them, and verifying that the equations hold.

Comment: Try working with some concrete examples (polynomials, rational functions) to see what a likely formula for the derivative of $f^*(z)$ should be. I personally think this is a really good problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(z)= u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ . Then $f^* (z) = u( x,-y) - i v(x, -y)$ . Now you can use C-R equation of $f$ to imply the C-R eqn of $f^*$.

Edited:

Let $g(x,y) = (x, -y)$, which is differentiable and $g_x =1, g_y=-1$. Now note that $u^* = u\circ g , v^* = -v\circ g$ , where $f^* = u^* +i v^*$ . Now you see how the chain rule works to imply that $u^*_x = u_x =v_y= v^*_y, \text{and } u^*_y = -u_y = v_x= - v^*_x $

Comment: Using C-R equations on $f$ we know, $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ how would we use this to imply the C-R of $f^*$

Comment: But if the CR hold for $f^*$, it doesn't necessary mean that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: For $f^*$ , we have $ u^* = u(x,-y) , v^* =-v (x,-y)$. Try to use the chain rule of derivative.

Comment: Please by all means do add the calculations to your answers. I don't believe this works.

Comment: @N.S. you are right. I am assuming u, v continuous. But I think it just follows from the assumption.

Comment: @jimmy , ok I updated my solution. Look if you have any question.

Comment: I fully understand it! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A map $f: D \to \mathbb C$ is complex differentiable if and only if it satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations, that is,

$$u_x = v_y$$ and 
$$u_y = - v_x$$ where $u$ is the real part of $f$ and $v$ is the imaginary part o $f$.

Since $f^\ast (z) = u^\ast(x,-y) - iv^\ast (x,-y)$ we have

$u^\ast_x  = u_x(x,-y)$

$u_y^\ast = - u_y(x,-y)$

$v^\ast_x = -v_x(x,-y)$

$v_y^\ast = v_y(x,-y)$

And since $u_x = v_y$ we have $u_x(x,-y) = v_y(x,-y)$ and since $u_y = -v_x$ we have $u_y(x,-y) = -v_x(x,-y)$. Now putting things together:

$$ u^\ast_x = u_x(x,-y) = v_y(x,-y) = v^\ast_y$$

and

$$ u^\ast_y = -u_y(x,-y) = v_x(x,-y) = - v_x^\ast$$

which shows that $f^\ast$ satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\frac{f^{*}(z)-f^{*}(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\overline{\frac{f(\bar z)-f(\bar{z_0})}{\bar{z}-\bar{z_0}}}$$

Now write every $z \in D^*$ as $z=\bar{w}$ with $w \in D$ and use that
$$\overline{\frac{f(\bar z)-f(\bar{z_0})}{\bar{z}-\bar{z_0}}}=\overline{\frac{f(w)-f(w_0)}{w-w_0}}$$
and that 
$$\lim_{w \to w_0}\frac{f(w)-f(w_0)}{w-w_0}=f'(w_0)$$

Answer (score 0):

let $\phi$ be the conjugation involution restricted to a map:
$$
\phi:D^* \to D
$$
then set
$$
f^* =\phi^{-1}\circ f \circ \phi: D^* \to D^*
$$
regarding all the maps as transformations of subdomains of $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $f=(u,v)$ we can see that $f^*=(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ is differentiable. so we have:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial\psi_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\psi_1}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial\psi_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\psi_2}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} 
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$
from which it is clear that $f^*$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations when $f$ does